# Custom class: interface to implement to work properly with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, interface

often I use LINQ to query, modify and manage lists (or dictionaries) of my custom classes.

It happened that ,for example, Contains method gave me strange result, and eventually I figured out that it expects IEquatable interface to be implemented to properly *understand* that the object was actually in the list.

Do you have handy a list of interface that my classes should implement to work fine with all the typical LINQ construct (as Discinct, Contains, Except etc)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `Equals` method on your class. If you don't override `Equals` then `Distinct` and `Contains` (etc) are checking to see if two items are actually both references to the same object. You probably want it to recognize two different objects that have the same properties.

Another option is to create another class that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`, and that class performs the comparison of two instances of `T`. The benefit there is that you don't have to modify the original class. Also, you can define different comparers so that for the purpose of one comparison two classes are equal, but in another comparison they aren't. You only use that `IEqualityComparer<T>` when you want it to apply.

Comment: You don't only need to override `Equals()` you must also override `GetHashCode()`

Answer (score 2):

`IEquatable` should be all you need to determine if one instance is *equal to* another.

If you plan on using your type as a key for a hashed collection (like `Dictionary` or `HashTable`), then you *have* to override `object.GetHashCode()` and `object.Equals(object)`.  Even if you *don't*, it's still a good idea, since overriding `object.Equals` is trivial if you've implemented `IEquatable`, and overriding `object.Equals(object)` requires that you override `GetHashCode` as well.